# Laravel 8 - How to query for a part of a name in a full name across multiple fields?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a query in laravel which looks like this:

```
        $adeudos = Adeudo::select('adeudo.*', 'adeudo_estatus.estatus', 'prestacion.nombre AS nombrePrestacion', 'vias_recuperacion.via AS viaRecuperacion', 'ente_publico.rfcPatronal AS rfcEnte', 
                                'ente_publico.nombre AS nombreEnte', 'relacion_laboral.numeroEmpleado', 'derechohabiente.rfc', 'derechohabiente.nombre', 'derechohabiente.primerApellido', 'derechohabiente.segundoApellido')
                            ->join('adeudo_estatus', 'adeudo_estatus.id', 'adeudo.idEstatus')
                            ->join('prestacion', 'prestacion.id', 'adeudo.idPrestacion')
                            ->join('vias_recuperacion', 'vias_recuperacion.id', 'adeudo.idViaRecuperacion')
                            ->join('relacion_laboral', 'relacion_laboral.id', 'adeudo.idRelacionLaboral')
                            ->join('derechohabiente', 'derechohabiente.id', 'adeudo.idDerechohabiente')
                            ->join('ente_publico', 'ente_publico.id', 'relacion_laboral.idEnte')
                            ->when($search, function($query, $search){
                                /*$query = $query->orWhere('derechohabiente.rfc', 'LIKE', '%{$search}%');*/
                                $query = $query->orWhereRaw("derechohabiente.rfc like '%$search%'");
                                $query = $query->orWhereRaw("derechohabiente.numeroIssstezac like '%$search%'");
                                return $query;
                            });
```

I want to search in multiple fields in case one of them matches the $search variable. The problem I'm having is with making a query that can filter if the $search variable contains a part or all of the full name of the 'derechohabiente' object.

The full name is divided in multiple fields, though, there is:

- name
- middleName
- lastName

So, if the full name is John Jeremy Jacobs, I'd like the query to return that name if the $search variable has something like "ohn", "ohn Jeremy", "John Jeremy J", etc.

Comment: You probably want to find John Smith if someone types Smith John too. I would split the words and search each word independently.

Comment: You have to add a selectRaw and concat the three columns (name, middleName, lastName) and then make the search using the concated alias used on the selectRaw. Not sure which database are you using, but on mysql I would use $query->selectRaw('CONCAT(\'name\', \'middleName\', \'lastName\') as name')->when($search, fn($q) => $q->where('name', "%$search%")).
Make sure to make the three unit tests to make sure the query is working ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$adeudos = Adeudo::select('adeudo.*', 'adeudo_estatus.estatus', 'prestacion.nombre AS nombrePrestacion', 'vias_recuperacion.via AS viaRecuperacion', 'ente_publico.rfcPatronal AS rfcEnte', 'ente_publico.nombre AS nombreEnte', 'relacion_laboral.numeroEmpleado', 'derechohabiente.rfc', 'derechohabiente.nombre', 'derechohabiente.primerApellido', 'derechohabiente.segundoApellido')
            ->join('adeudo_estatus', 'adeudo_estatus.id', 'adeudo.idEstatus')
            ->join('prestacion', 'prestacion.id', 'adeudo.idPrestacion')
            ->join('vias_recuperacion', 'vias_recuperacion.id', 'adeudo.idViaRecuperacion')
            ->join('relacion_laboral', 'relacion_laboral.id', 'adeudo.idRelacionLaboral')
            ->join('derechohabiente', 'derechohabiente.id', 'adeudo.idDerechohabiente')
            ->join('ente_publico', 'ente_publico.id', 'relacion_laboral.idEnte')
            ->when(!empty($search), function($q, $search) {
        $q->where(function($query) use ($input) {
            $query->orWhere(DB::raw('CONCAT(derechohabiente.first_name, " ", derechohabiente.middle_name," ",derechohabiente.last_name)'), 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('derechohabiente.first_name', ' ', 'derechohabiente.last_name')"), 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('derechohabiente.last_name', ', ', 'derechohabiente.first_name')"), 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('derechohabiente.first_name', ' ', 'derechohabiente.middle_name', ' ', 'last_name')"), 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('derechohabiente.last_name', ', ', 'derechohabiente.first_name', ' ', 'derechohabiente.middle_name')"), 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('derechohabiente.first_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('derechohabiente.middle_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('derechohabiente.last_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhereRaw("derechohabiente.rfc like '%$search%'");
        });
    });
```

users might search for names in various ways.
I hope it would work for you.

Comment: When I do the DB::raw, I get the error "Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\PrestamosCreditos\\DB' not found"

Comment: use DB; add this namespace